# How does one change default options in CUPS

Tags: printing, cups

I want to change default print settings in CUPS.

I'm mass printing PDF's through Finder and it won't use my preset in the printer options menu so I'm fiddling around in CUPS to see if that works. I want to change the settings as shown below, but I can't find out how?

Essentially I'm trying to print all pdf's with Scale to fit enabled, if there is some other way I should be doing this. I'd like the heads up :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since I essentially wanted to print all pdf's with Scale to fit enabled. This small command worked.

```
lpoptions -o fit-to-page
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the drop-down list that reads "Administration". One of the other options there is "Set Default Options".

You can then modify the default options of your printer. However, whether "Scale to Fit" is shown as an option will depend on the printer's characteristics.